# Eclipse — Add Space After Square Bracket (Formatter)

Tags: java, eclipse

What I am looking for is very similar to what can be found here: [Eclipse: Adding Spaces to Parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560131/eclipse-adding-spaces-to-parentheses)

However, I also need to do this for square brackets.

For example:

```
array[index] => array[ index ]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as in the referenced answer but on `Whitespace -> Arrays` section.
Remember to work on a copy of the built-in formatter using the `New` button for backup purposes .

[image]

> Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
> Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
> Build id: 20210612-2011
> Java version: 11.0.11